# Update product stock in Algolia index when after checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, algolia

Im having a problem getting Algolia to reindex a products stock level once an order is placed through woo commerce. Not sure what function I should use to trigger the algolia_update_post_meta.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
what I have so far taken from:https://www.algolia.com/doc/integration/wordpress/indexing/automatic-updates/?language=php

Hey @Olivier  Sorry that was my bad, I do have that just missed it out in the above paste.

I have also updated the above code to include a few other details.

so first we get the product meta data so Algolia knows what to index.

```
function add_product_shared_attributes( array $shared_attributes, WP_Post $post ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( $post );

    $shared_attributes['price'] =  $product->get_price();
    $shared_attributes['availability'] =  $product->get_availability();
    $shared_attributes['stock_status'] =  $product->get_stock_status();
    $shared_attributes['regular_price'] =  $product->get_regular_price();
    $shared_attributes['sale_price'] =  $product->get_sale_price();
    $shared_attributes['is_on_sale'] =  $product->is_on_sale();
    $shared_attributes['sku'] = $product->get_sku();
    $shared_attributes['stock'] =  $product->get_stock_quantity();
    $shared_attributes['attributes'] = (array) $product->get_attributes();

    return $shared_attributes;
}

add_filter( 'algolia_post_product_shared_attributes', 'add_product_shared_attributes', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'algolia_searchable_post_product_shared_attributes', 'add_product_shared_attributes', 10, 2 );
```

- the above works great - no issues there.

Then we try to update the stock meta Algolia side when an order is placed. This isn't working for whatever reason and i'm stumped?

```
function algolia_update_post_meta($meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value) {
    global $algolia;
    $indexedMetaKeys = ['stock'];

    if (in_array($meta_key, $indexedMetaKeys)) {
        $index = $algolia->initIndex(
            apply_filters('algolia_index_name', 'wp_posts_product')
        );

        $index->partialUpdateObject([
            'objectID' => 'post#'.$object_id,
            $meta_key => $_meta_value,
        ]);
    }
}

add_action('update_post_meta', 'algolia_update_post_meta', 10, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed the very last line of the sample code in the documentation page you're linking to:

```
add_action('update_post_meta', 'algolia_update_post_meta', 10, 4);
```

This, positioned **outside** of your `algolia_update_post_meta`, would let Wordpress/WooCommerce know that the `algolia_update_post_meta` must be called whenever the `update_post_meta` action is called.

And this action will be called by Wordpress [from the `update_post_meta()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-includes/meta.php#L151) function (yes, same name), so when a post's metadata is being udpated.

So unless I have missed something myself, your code is just missing that one line:

```
function algolia_update_post_meta($meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value) {
    global $algolia;
    $indexedMetaKeys = ['stock_quantity'];

    if (in_array($meta_key, $indexedMetaKeys)) {
        $index = $algolia->initIndex(
            apply_filters('algolia_index_name', 'wp_posts_product')
        );

        $index->partialUpdateObject([
            'objectID' => 'post#'.$object_id,
            $meta_key => $_meta_value,
        ]);
    }
}

add_action('update_post_meta', 'algolia_update_post_meta', 10, 4);
```